# Invalid value for attachdbfilename

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

I'm currently trying to distribute a application that relies on some form of database in .NET. I am trying to use SQL Server Express or SQL Server Express LocalDB.

For accessing the database I am using the entity framework.

Now the target is to create a deployable version that does not require any alterations on the SQL server by hand. It needs to install and setup as far as needed to launch the application. All goes well on my development computer. How ever once deploying to another computer the problems begin.

I tried the LocalDB in order to avoid the requirement to setup the database structure by hand on the target machine. How ever upon launching the application its reports a problem with the connection string. The attachdbfilename is not valid.

This filename is set to `attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\database\Db.mdf`
As I said. On my development maschine this works. Both when using the deployed files and when running it from the IDE. Yet the target mashine reports the problem. I installed the SQL Server Express 2012 LocalDB using ClickOnce along with my application. The deployed files contain the mdf file in the proper directory.

The full connection strings are:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/database.DbModel.csdl|res://*/database.DbModel.ssdl|res://*/database.DbModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\database\Db.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I fail to see a reason why the attachdbfilename is not valid. The installation of the sql server on the target machine seems to be okay.

I also tried to pulish it with the normal SQL Server 2012 express. How ever I assume if I want to use this, without a attached database file I need to create the required database by hand. And that is not a option.

I read in some questions that this indicates a problem with the create `ObjectContext` but this one is looking good as well:

```
Public Partial Class DbContainer
    Inherits ObjectContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("name=DbContainer", "DbContainer")
        MyBase.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true
        OnContextCreated()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal connectionString As String)
        MyBase.New(connectionString, "DbContainer")
        MyBase.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true
        OnContextCreated()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal connection As EntityConnection)
        MyBase.New(connection, "DbContainer")
        MyBase.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true
        OnContextCreated()
    End Sub
    ...
```

Just like it got generated by the entity framework.

I am running out of ideas on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem turned out to be the `|DataDirectory|`

I replace this entry in the connection string by hand using the proper one click data directory I optained using:

```
Dim dataDir As String
If ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then
    Dim ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment
    dataDir = ad.DataDirectory
Else
    dataDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
End If
```

No problem loading the database file anymore. I can't say why the replacement of the `|DataDirectory|` is not working. For the version on the development computer this is simply replace with a empty string... and this works because the working directory is the parent of the refered database directory.

How ever when using ClickOnce the data files, including the database, is located in a different directory. This causes the connect string to fail. The code above fixes this problem. I can't explain for what reason this is not working out of the box.